# Angular Disable href using TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I been having problem with disabling an href using Angular and Typescript and I am not sure if I am going in the correct path.

Is there a better way to do something like this?  looking for something like this with the red circle

[image]

ts

```
ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes = true;
  }
```

html

```
<a href="#" 
*ngIf="note.Edited || note.Removed" 
(click)="restoreDefault(note)" 
style="font-size: 12px"
data-disabled="readOnlyStyleGuideNotes">
restore defaults
</a>
```

css class

```
 a[data-disabled=true] {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointer events None and wrap the a element with span so that you can apply cursor

```
 <span [ngStyle]="{'cursor':readOnlyStyleGuideNotes ? 'not-allowed' :''}"><a 
 [ngClass]="{'disable':readOnlyStyleGuideNotes}" href="#"  
 (click)="restoreDefault(note)" 
 style="font-size: 12px">
 restore defaults</a></span>
```

**css**

```
.disable{
  color: currentColor; 
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-22f9ts

Comment: when I set readOnlyStyleGuideNotes = false; it looks like disable?

Comment: you mean the color?

Comment: Correct it is still that light gray

Comment: can you check the stackblitz now

Comment: One last problem can I use a custom css class and not use span{} and a{}?

Comment: how would I do that in [ngClass] and base it off of the boolean ?

Comment: did you check the updated answer i have added class disable to disable the anchor element

Comment: why is it when you set the value in ngOnInit() it stops working?

Comment: What value are you setting inside ngOnInit

Comment: I am setting the boolean  ngOnInit() {this.readOnlyStyleGuideNotes = model.ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes;}

Comment: you can initialise the variable with false value why are you doing inside ngOnInit